Jump state in AnimGraph is not entered when character jumps
I finished following the "setting up character movement" gameplay tutorial and everything works, except for the jump animation, which does not play when jumping. I determined that the issue lies in the the fact that the state machine never transitions to the jump state even though the logic is identical to the documentation. It transitions into the crouch state properly, but not the the jump state. Here is a github repository of the project: https://github.com/sebastian-giordano/SKGSF
Demonstration
Event graph of AnimBP


Why is your crouching set connecting into the jumping set?

@Zibelas Because thats how epic sets it up in the docs
